# ExpectedException attribute is not present yet in Unit Test App (Windows Universal)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I currently working on Unit Test App (Windows Universal) project using .NET Framework 4.6. I would like to add ExpectedException attribute on my test method, but it seems I cannot found the attribute within its Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework namespace. Anyone have an answer for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExpectedExeception` attribute was removed/never added to the windows runtime.  use `Assert.ThrowsException` instead.